# Automatic opening of a modal window in apex oracle, when creating a new record through api

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I have created an application for checkpoint. I created an API for this (when attaching the card to the shield, the oracle is written in the table, the card number, shielding time, employee, etc.). I want that when the card was attached and the record was made, in my application, on a special page, a modal window would open with the data that I write in the table. Is it possible to do ??

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a possibility to open a modal page from PL/SQL.

But what you can do is prepare the URL you need using APEX_PAGE.GET_URL, during your API call. Return the generated URL and use that URL in a javascript call apex.navigation.dialog(url) afterwards.

That can be done using a dynamic action, which is fired after your API call has been successfully completed.

Does this answer your question?